# how to use postMessage to communicate from nested iFrames to the root document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, nested, postmessage

I'm developing a plugin which has to manage fairly complex pages with nested `iframes` like this:

```
page.html
<body>
 <iframe A>
  <iframe B>
   <div bla></div>
  </iframe>
 </iframe>
 <iframe C>
   <div foo></div>
 </iframe>
</body>
```

The plugin will run in multiple instances (one on the main page, one for each iFrame). To inform iFrames about the `root` instance, I'm passing the root URL as a parameter when generaring the iFrame like so:

```
 ...
 newHTML = document.createElement("iframe");
 newHTML.setAttribute("src", options.src + "?" + priv.encodeURI(rootPath));
```

So the iFrame will be loaded with a URL like this:

```
 http://www.path/to/iFrame.html?base=...encodeURI(window.location.href.of.root)
```

My problem is, I need to `postMessage` from a nested iFrame to the root and I cannot get it to work. Here is what I'm doing:

```
// sending a message
var adressArray = window.location.href.split("?");
options.src = options.src || adressArray[0];
window.postMessage(options, options.src);

// receiving
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
  console.log(event.origin);
  console.log(window);
}
```

My problem is, both the call and the listener are in the same plugin, but should listen in different instances of the plugin. So the `postmessage` will be fired by the instance of `frame B` for example and the listener on my `page.html` instance should detect the message.

I thought the [targetOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) property was to specify the **destination** of where the postMessage should be sent to. Instead I'm ending up sending the URL of my posting iFrame (**B**), which gets recorded by the parent iFrame (**A**) instead of the page.html instance listening for it.

**Question:**
Is it possible to send a postMessage "across" two (or any number of) parents, without articifially "bubbling" it up the tree? Say the instance of iFrame **B** wants to say "Hello" to the instance of **page.html**, how would I do this using `postMessage`, when I can make the "root instance URL" available to every iFrame?

Thanks!

**Question:**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.top` seems to be my friend as it returns the top-most window element.

When I postMessage to:

```
var top = window.top;
top.postMessage("foo", currentFrameUrl);
```

it's working correctly.

I will continue passing the URL though, because on cross domain iFrames, `window.top` will surely not work...

Answer (score 0):

`parent.postMessage("foo");` should do the trick if you're only looking to go up one level of nesting.
Note: `window` is implied, so you're actually executing `window.parent.postMessage("foo");`

The 2nd argument is only necessary if you're working cross-origin (i.e., if your parent and nested iframes have a different protocol/subdomain/domain/port), in which case `"*"` is a technically-acceptable solution to send a postMessage cross-origin—although that's arguably less secure.